# Qual è il senso di "aggiustarsi al largo" in questo passaggio?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *La malora*, di Beppe Fenoglio, ho letto:

> Andiamo ad aggiustarci da tutt’un’altra parte: in val di Diano, se possiamo. C’è un ragazzo del mio paese che ha la fortuna d’essersi aggiustato in val di Diano, e io gli ho parlato insieme una volta. Bisognava sentire, e ci gioco la testa che erano tutte verità, non che dicesse solo per farmi invidia. A parte la terra che là è piú tenera, la mentalità di quei padroni là, che al paragone i nostri fanno schifo e si meriterebbero una zappata sulla testa. Là alla domenica i padroni ai servitori gli regalano a testa una coppia d’uova da cambiare alla censa col tabacco da fumare tutta la festa, ti dànno licenza di ricevere i tuoi amici nella loro cantina, e non parliamo del vino, ma c’è sempre a disposizione un cestone di pane e un bariletto di peperoni sott’olio. È inutile, se hai per destino che Santo Stefano sia la tua festa, devi **aggiustarti al largo**.

Potresti spiegarmi cosa significa "aggiustarsi al largo" in questo brano? Ho cercato alla voce "largo" in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho saputo trovare niente che abbia senso in questo contesto.

Comment: Come detto in una precedente risposta, aggiustarti al largo significa accontentarti, arrangiarti come meglio puoi con le  scarse risorse che hai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aggiustarsi* compare due volte all'inizio del capoverso con il senso di *sistemarsi*, riportato anche nel [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/aggiustare/):

> 2. rifl. […] b. region. Sistemarsi: *speravano di aggiustarsi in una grossa cascina e lavorare tutti quanti e star bene* (Pavese).

*Aggiustarsi al largo* significa “doversi sistemare lontano”.

Comment: quindi nel senso di "emigrare"

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi Direi di sì.

Comment: Ma forse non necessariamente adarsene a un altro paese.